# PHP foreach - search match from multidimensional array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, foreach, match

I have a array

```
    $Cat[0]['name']     = "garfield 1";
$Cat[0]['color']    = "brown";
$Cat[0]['weight']   = "15";
$Cat[0]['age']      = "3";

    $Cat[1]['name']     = "garfield 2";
$Cat[1]['color']    = "brown";
$Cat[1]['weight']   = "15";
$Cat[1]['age']      = "3";
```

The search word "gar" should return data of both cats.
And search word "garfield 1" to return only the data of cat[0]

Answer (score 1):

Look at [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function

Answer (score 0):

```
$garCats = array_filter($Cat, function($catDetails) { 
                                  return (strpos($catDetails['name'],'gar') !== FALSE); 
                              } 
                       );
```

EDIT

```
$searchString = 'gar';
$garCats = array_filter($Cat, function($catDetails) use($searchString) { 
                                  return (strpos($catDetails['name'],$searchString) !== FALSE); 
                              } 
                       );
```